# Ошибка в фиксированной верстке

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. У меня есть сайт и я хочу сделать на него фиксированую верстку я посмотрел в интернете способ нужно вставить  и body {min-width: 1440px;} и он на пк версиях отображается с горизонтальным скролом а на мобилке вообще кривой. вот сайт: http://chornyjq.beget.tech/sanstar/

Comment: а что вы ожидаете увидеть на мобилке, указывая 1440 ширину?

Comment: я хочу чтобы сайт отображался на мобилке хорошо да с мелким шрифтом но все же. подскажите как сделать правильно

Comment: сделать не фиксированную, а адаптивную верстку

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

У вас body 1440px, а элементы не имеют фиксированной ширины, там есть элементы к примеру intro__img с `position: absolute;` а родительского блока с `position: relative;` нет. Короче там всё плавает, простого и быстрого способа  для оптимизации под мобильники нет (вроде этого `body {min-width: 1440px;}` ). Нужно медиа запросы писать.